# How to convert unicode emoji into hex codepoint (with multiple groups)

Tags: javascript, emoji, codepoint, twemoji

I'm building an application that converts emoji shortnames (like :flag_cf:) and converts them through a series of operations into a hex codepoint (which are the keys in a map to return Twitter emoji/twemoji).

I have a utility ([emojione.shortnameToUnicode()](https://demos.emojione.com/latest/shortnametounicode.html)) that converts the shortnames into native unicode emoji, but I'm having trouble with converting the native unicode emoji into hex codepoints.

I've been using:

```
const unicode = emojione.shortnameToUnicode(str);
const decCodepoint = unicode.codePointAt(0);
const hexCodepoint = decCodepoint.toString(16);
```

This works fine when the resulting hex codepoint is a single figure. However, emoji like flags seem to have two, like `:flag_cn:` is `1f1f9-1f1f7`. However, my process above would only return the first hex codepoint (namely `1f1f9`).

Comment: Hi, not sure if you already get this working but my solution will be using 


    String.fromCharCode 

more info [here](https://delicious-insights.com/en/posts/js-strings-unicode/)